# Validate unique name and firstname in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I know the subject exists, but I haven't found a solution so far. I have a table which is named `players` with two fields: `name,` `firstname.` My goal is to have neither duplicate when I enter several entries.

I want to get this result.

```
Fostier | Alain 
Fostier | Jeremy
```

If I have two times 
Fostier | Alain it's not correct.

The duplicate system should combine only the ID? I have tried the following without success.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|unique:players,name',
        'firstname' => 'required|unique:players,firstname',

    ]);
    Player::create($request->all());

    flashy('Valider');

    return redirect()->route('players.index')
        ->with('success', 'save');
}
```

Comment: Out of the box, the `unique` method doesn't handle concatenation/compound columns. This will require some custom logic, such as performing a separate query for a player that exists with that first/last name, or storing a slug on your table and referencing that in your `unique` rule, etc etc.

Comment: @TimLewis Comments are not ment for answers or partials answers.  That seems like it could turn into a nice answer with a bit of work.

Comment: @J.A.Streich You're correct, but my comment isn't really an answer per-say; it's more guidelines on different approaches available. It would take a lot of work to turn it into an answer, which falls under the "Too broad" close reason. I'll leave it as a comment, if the user wants to attempt one of these they can self-close or update with any new, more specific errors.

Comment: @Tim Lewis: Thank you for your explicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Illuminate\Validation\Rule` class to make compound check e.g:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
...

$request->validate([
    'name' => ['required', Rule::unique('players', 'name')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        return $query->where('name','!=', $request->input('firstname'));
    })],
    'firstname' => ['required', Rule::unique('players', 'firstname')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        return $query->where('firstname', '!=', $request->input('name'));
    })],
]);
```

This checks uniqueness of the 'firstname' by also checking if the 'name' is in use, and also does the same for 'name' checking the 'firstname' with it.

Comment: Thank you a lot :-)