# how to make validation on composite unique key

Tags: php, laravel

i have three columns in my database ,

i need to make a validation for these columns ,

and to make the tree of them unique.

```
 Validator::make($request->all(),
        [

        'name' => 'required|min:4|string',
        'color'=>'required',
        'size_id'=>'required',

        ]);
```

i already tried

```
   Validator::make($request->all(),
    [
    'name' => 'required|min:4|string|unique:products,name,color,size_id',
    'color'=>'required|unique:products,color,name,size_id',
    'size_id'=>'required|unique:products,size_id,name,color',
     ]);
```

and i tried this

```
$color = $request->input('color');
        $size_id = $request->input('size_id');
        $name = $request->input('name');
        // dd($name);
        return 
        Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
        'name' => 'required|min:4|string|unique:products,name,'.'NULL'.',color,'.$color.',size_id,'.$size_id,
        'description'=>'required|min:4',
        'quantity'=>'required|numeric',
        'subcategory_id'=> 'required',
        'category_id'=> 'required',
        'price'=> 'required|numeric',
        'color'=>'required|unique:products,color,'.'NULL'.',name,'.$name.',size_id,'.$size_id,
        'size_id'=>'required|unique:products,size_id,'.'NULL'.',name,'.$name.',color,'.$color,
        'cover'=>'required|image:png,jpg,jpeg', 
        // 'images'=>'image:png,jpg,jpeg', 
        'images.

*'=>'image:png,jpg,jpeg', 
        ]);
```

but it return undefined offset 3 when i check if it fails or not!
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [composite-unique-key-validation - laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093061/composite-unique-key-validation-laravel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856668/validate-unique-name-and-firstname-in-laravel?

Comment: i already tried this but when i check if validate fails it return 
offset 3 not found !
any idea what is that

Answer (score 0):

```
    $color = $request->get('color');
    $size_id = $request->get('size_id');
    $name = $request->get('name');
    // dd($name);
    return 
    Validator::make($request->all(),
    [
    'name' => 'required|min:4|string|unique:products,name,NULL,id,color,'.$color.',size_id,'.$size_id,
    'description'=>'required|min:4',
    'quantity'=>'required|numeric',
    'subcategory_id'=> 'required',
    'category_id'=> 'required',
    'price'=> 'required|numeric',
    'color'=>'required|unique:products,color,NULL,id,name,'.$name.',size_id,'.$size_id,
    'size_id'=>'required|unique:products,size_id,NULL,id,name,'.$name.',color,'.$color,
    'cover'=>'required|image:png,jpg,jpeg', 
    // 'images'=>'image:png,jpg,jpeg', 
    'images.*'=>'image:png,jpg,jpeg', 
    ]);
```

the code above solved my problem